# Verify whether the set is subspace or not :(method to solve & meaning please)

Tags: linear-algebra

Verify whether the set of
Sequences that are absolutely summable. (A sequence $(x_k)$  is absolutely summable if$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }|x_k|<\infty $)
is a subspace of $R^{\infty}$ or not.

Comment: You should prove if $x,y$ are in this set, then $zx+y$ is in this set too

Comment: but what does set of sequences that are absolutely summable means????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You must show that the set of absolutely summable series is stable under addition and scalar multiplication. Go back to the definition of summable as the existence of a limit of the sequence of finite sums of n terms. Use the fact that a non-decreasing sequence has a limit iff it is bounded above. You will need to use $ |ca_i|=|c||a_i| $ and
$ |a_i+b_i|\le|a_i|+|b_i| $ . Then sum the equations/inequalities from 1 to n and take limits as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @P.Lawrece are concluding that it is a subspace of R infinity